# "Yup" Validation Library fails to compile in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I have been turned to using the Yup library for form validation on my project however when I have installed it (and tried many many more times after that) I have been encountering this extremely odd library error consistently.

How can I get past this?

```
Failed to compile.

C:/Users/x/Documents/y/frontend/node_modules/yup/lib/array.d.ts
TypeScript error in C:/Users/x/Documents/y/frontend/node_modules/yup/lib/array.d.ts(2,13):
'=' expected.  TS1005

    1 | import { MixedLocale } from './locale';
  > 2 | import type { AnyObject, InternalOptions, Callback, Message, Maybe, Preserve, Optionals } from './types';
      |             ^
    3 | import type Reference from './Reference';
    4 | import { Asserts, Defined, If, Thunk, TypeOf } from './util/types';
    5 | import BaseSchema, { AnySchema, SchemaInnerTypeDescription, SchemaSpec } from './schema';
```

Comment: Have you installed "@types/yup"?

Comment: Yeah! Sadly that didn't solve the error and the error persisted :(

Comment: It seems that from version "0.32.1" it is no longer recommended to install "@ types / yup". They provide their own types since then. I updated yup to the latest version "0.32.8" with no compilation issues.

Check their TypeScript support [page](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/HEAD/docs/typescript.md)

Comment: To be super specific I ran the command 
```npm install @types/yup```
Then as soon as I import it breaks the app with that exact same error.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! So I went back and just npm uninstalled the Yup libraries. Both the @types/yup and the default yup. Went back to install the regular yup like ```npm install yup --save``` Unfortunately I am hitting the exact same error even now ><

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup project's verison `0.32.8` uses TypeScript version `v4.0.5`.

Feature `import type` which compiler complains is supported since TypeScript `v3.8`

> This feature is something most users may never have to think about; however, if you’ve hit issues under --isolatedModules, TypeScript’s transpileModule API, or Babel, this feature might be relevant.
>
> ```js
> import type { SomeThing } from "./some-module.js";
> export type { SomeThing };
> ```

source: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html

Comment: @CoreyRyden Would you mind sharing the solution/code on how you fixed your issue? I am running into the exact same issue and I'm very new to Typescript.

Comment: @exlnt `package.json` contains TypeScript version, bump it to `3.8` or above, then run `npm install`